# How do declarative layout and uibinder work?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Hey all, I have 2 questions, could you please help me...

1. I want to know how does the `createAndBindUi()` method technically work?
2. If I want to make UIBinder template dynamically, what can I do? I know that UIBinder works at compile time but is there anyway to implement something like that which works at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [the javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/uibinder/client/UiBinder.html#createAndBindUi%28O%29) and in [google's example](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/uibinder/client/UiBinder.html#createAndBindUi%28O%29) createAndBindUi() uses an existing UIBinder. If you want to create the design on runtime you don't need a UIBinder.

So the solution depends on what exactly you are trying to do :

> is there anyway to implement something like that ?

Like what ?

If you need to reuse a UI design you could create a new widget.